# wxStreamToTextRedirector newlines are lost

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am getting result from wxStreamToTextRedirector **as one line**. The newlines are lost ....
 wxStreamToTextRedirector  with just one parameter supposed to redirect output to cout, I have
 no clue why the newlines are not treated by cout, as such...

**Update: a simplified example:** produces the same result i.e newlines are lost.

```
    textctrl = new wxTextCtrl(this, -1, wxT(""), wxPoint(-1, -1),
     wxSize(250, 150));
{
    wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(textctrl);
       string result = "line1\n Line2\n";
      cout << result;

}

Output ---> line1 Line2, as appears in the textctrl window. May it be that textctrl  
window does not interpret
\n correctly? I am using wxWidets on a Windows machine.
```

Comment: Can you simplify the example further, to get rid of the irrelevant (I think) `lDir()`? I.e. what doing just `cout << "Line 1\nLine 2\n";` result in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a `wxTextCtrl`, by default it is created without support for multiple lines. You have to tell it that you intend to use multiple lines. If you are using Code::Blocks with wxSmith (which I recommend), you can specify that in the properties of the `wxTextCtrl`:

[image: Multiline properties]

If you are creating it manually with code, you only need to specify `wxTE_MULTILINE` in the *style* parameter of the constructor, like this:

```
textctrl = new wxTextCtrl(this, -1, wxT(""), wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(250, 150),wxTE_MULTILINE);
```

For more information, you can check [this page  about the possible styles](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html), and in particular, [this section](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html#a4f398e4800a904fdf225fabc366d7910) about the constructor.

Comment: Yes, wxTE_MULTILINE made output appear multiline, tnanks! Yes, I am using Code::Blocks, as for wxWigets i'm leaning it, it is not a week yet. Looks like C++ with Code::Blocks and Boost and wxWidets is a mighty bundle.

Comment: @user2972119, I have tried to up vote, but got a message that I need t have at least 15 points for that. Is accepting different from upvoting ? I do not see any buttons for accepting ...